# Drag-able div and click to behind element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What i exactly want ?**

> make element clickable that is behind movable div.

**Here is what i have tried** for achieve that but its not working. And i did not found any other solution for this. This will be great help for me.

> add style "pointer-events: none;" but after applying this style then that
>   div is no drag-able.

**Here is my code :**

Red Div is movable but **not clickable** and Green Div is clickable but **not movable**.

```js
function make_movable(id) {

  var movable_div = document.getElementById(id);
  movable_div.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }


  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    movable_div.style.top = (movable_div.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    movable_div.style.left = (movable_div.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }

}

make_movable("movable_div1");
make_movable("movable_div2");
```

```css
#movable_div1 {
  cursor: move;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#movable_div2 {
  cursor: move;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 1');">BUTTON 1</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 2');">BUTTON 2</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 3');">BUTTON 3</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 4');">BUTTON 4</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 5');">BUTTON 5</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 6');">BUTTON 6</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 7');">BUTTON 7</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 8');">BUTTON 8</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 9');">BUTTON 9</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 10');">BUTTON 10</button>

<div id="movable_div1" style="top: 40px; left: 40px;"> </div>
<div id="movable_div2" style="top: 160px; left: 40px;"> </div>
```

Comment: It's not possible for the blocks to be movable AND let mouse clicks pass through them and click the buttons behind them. How would you differentiate between a click on a button and a move on the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but a bit *messy*!

You can check if the user did move the mouse between the `mousedown`- and `mouseup`-events. If the mouse did not move, we assume the user did a click. Now we only need to hide the moveable-element for a brief moment and use that to find the element that is at the current mouse-position topmost. Then we create a new `MouseEvent`-event *(click)* and dispatch it to the underlying-element before we make the moveable-element visible again.

Example:

```js
function make_movable(id) {
  var movable_div = document.getElementById(id);
  movable_div.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  let didDrag = false; // did the user perform a drag (mousemove)

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    didDrag = false;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    didDrag = true;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    movable_div.style.top = (movable_div.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    movable_div.style.left = (movable_div.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (!didDrag) {
      // copy display-property of moveable-element
      let displayCopy = movable_div.style.display;
      // hide moveable-element
      movable_div.style.display = 'none';
      // get x- and y-position from current event
      let x = e.clientX,
          y = e.clientY;
      // create click event with position
      let event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clientX: x,
        clientY: y
      });
      // get underlying-element at mouse-position
      let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
      // restore display-property of moveable-element
      movable_div.style.display = displayCopy;
      // dispatch event for the underlying-element
      element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

make_movable("movable_div1");
make_movable("movable_div2");
make_movable("movable_div3");
```

```css
#movable_div1 {
  cursor: move;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#movable_div2 {
  cursor: move;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

#movable_div3 {
  cursor: move;
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 1');">BUTTON 1</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 2');">BUTTON 2</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 3');">BUTTON 3</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 4');">BUTTON 4</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 5');">BUTTON 5</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 6');">BUTTON 6</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 7');">BUTTON 7</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 8');">BUTTON 8</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 9');">BUTTON 9</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 10');">BUTTON 10</button>

<div id="movable_div1" style="top: 40px; left: 40px;"> </div>
<div id="movable_div2" style="top: 160px; left: 40px;"> </div>
<div id="movable_div3" style="top: 40px; left: 160px;"> </div>
```

*Tested with Firefox 67 (macOS).*

Comment: its exactly what i am looking for. :)

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal The red div is movable AND clickable. I am just wondering if this is what you want or I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Hikarunomemory Yes this is what i want. its working perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to check if a user is clicking or dragging.

```
timer = setTimeout(() => {
  document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  isDragging = true;
}, 400);
```

If `onmousedown` event is triggered more than 400ms and `onmouseup` event is not being triggered yet, we can assume that the user is trying to drag the element. And if `onmouseup` event is triggered in 400ms, we can assume that the user is trying to click the element or the button behind it.

```
function tryClick(e) {
  var { clientX, clientY } = e;
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
  if (element.classList.contains("clickable")) {
    element.hidden = true;
    tryClick(e);
    element.hidden = false;
  } else if (element.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    element.click();
  }
}
```

The `tryClick` function is a recursive function that checks if the element that the mouse is currently pointed is `clickable`. If it is, hide it and check the element behind it and so on. If it's not, check if the element is a `BUTTON` and trigger `click` if it is.

```js
function make_movable(id) {

  var movable_div = document.getElementById(id);
  movable_div.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  var timer = null,
      isDragging = false;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;

    // check if the element is movable
    if (!movable_div.classList.contains("movable")) return;

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      isDragging = true;
    }, 400);
  }


  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    movable_div.style.top = (movable_div.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    movable_div.style.left = (movable_div.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    if (!isDragging) {
      tryClick(e);
    } else {
      isDragging = false;
    }
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }

  function tryClick(e) {
    var { clientX, clientY } = e;
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    if (element.classList.contains("clickable")) {
      element.hidden = true;
      tryClick(e);
      element.hidden = false;
    } else if (element.tagName == "BUTTON") {
      element.click();
    }
  }
}

make_movable("movable_div1");
make_movable("movable_div2");
make_movable("movable_div3");
```

```css
#movable_div1 {
  cursor: move;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#movable_div2 {
  cursor: move;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

#movable_div3 {
  cursor: move;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 1');">BUTTON 1</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 2');">BUTTON 2</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 3');">BUTTON 3</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 4');">BUTTON 4</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 5');">BUTTON 5</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 6');">BUTTON 6</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 7');">BUTTON 7</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 8');">BUTTON 8</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 9');">BUTTON 9</button>
<button onClick="alert('Just pressed button 10');">BUTTON 10</button>

<div id="movable_div1" class="clickable" style="top: 40px; left: 40px;"> </div>
<div id="movable_div2" class="movable" style="top: 160px; left: 40px;"> </div>
<div id="movable_div3" class="movable clickable" style="top: 40px; left: 160px;"> </div>
```